Why do we use the minimal free $R$-resolution of a factor ring $R/I$ when we want information from the minimal resolution of an ideal $I$?
I have noticed that projective dimension (in my case, the length of the minimal free resolution, I'm not dealing with the more general "projective modules" case) and Betti numbers of an ideal are often calculated using  the minimal free $R$-resolution of the factor ring $R/I$, instead of the minimal free resolution of $I$. Why is this?
I have tried to argue that if given the minimal resolution of $I$, I can just "concatenate" the exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/I \rightarrow 0$$ to get a free resolution of $R/I$. If this was minimal, it would explain the relations between the numerical invariants of $I$ to the ones of $R/I$. But I can't figure out if / why it is a minimal resolution. If it helps, I'm specifically interested in the case where $R$ is a polynomial ring over a field. Sorry if this has been asked / is trivial.
